# Align items in RowLayout with Layout.alignment

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I want to align some items in a **RowLayout** from left to right. Actually I am working with anchors which gives me the warnings:

```
QML MouseArea: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead

QML Row: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead
```

If I use **Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter** in **RowLayout** level or item level, I have no warnings but the view is ugly.

```
RowLayout {
    spacing: 2
    anchors.fill: parent

    Label {
        id: titleText
        text: ""
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: dragMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Row {
        anchors { right: parent.right; verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter}
        [...]
    }

    Item {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved it. I had to add `Layout.fillHeight: true` and use `Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter` in every item in `RowLayout` instead of using anchors

Answer (score 0):

You can use this property in rowLayout called layout direction

some thing like this in your case

```
RowLayout {
      spacing: 2
      anchors.fill: parent
      layoutDirection: "LeftToRight"
      Item {
          id: xyz
          ...
          ...
          ...
      }
  }
```

Do not use anchors when you are trying to embed items/objects inside layouts

Comment: Well but my main problem is to align all items vertically in the layout. How can I do this?

Comment: you can use columnLayout / Column object for vertical layout